# Subclassing NSArray & NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, subclassing

The references for [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) mention the possibility to create subclasses, but this is only possible by providing your own backing store and implementation of the methods

- `count`
- `objectAtIndex:`

for `NSArray`, as well as

- `insertObject:atIndex:`
- `removeObjectAtIndex:`
- `addObject:`
- `removeLastObject`
- `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`

for `NSMutableArray`. This can be misleading in that it leads the programmer to think that it is not possible by simple means to subclass `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.

Thought it is not possible to create "simple" subclasses of them that make use of the existing backing store (even when you don't access them directly), it IS still possible by a little "workaround".

So while i was looking for a possibility to still be able to subclass them, i had a simple idea: Just create subclasses and use an instance of `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` as backing store.

Here is how it works:

### CSSMutableArray.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface CSSMutableArray : NSMutableArray {
    NSMutableArray *_backingStore;
}

@end
```

### CSSMutableArray.m

```
#import "CSSMutableArray.h"


@implementation CSSMutableArray

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _backingStore = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [_backingStore release];
    _backingStore = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark NSArray

-(NSUInteger)count
{
    return [_backingStore count];
}

-(id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{   
    return [_backingStore objectAtIndex:index];
}

#pragma mark NSMutableArray

-(void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    [_backingStore insertObject:anObject atIndex:index];
}

-(void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    [_backingStore removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}

-(void)addObject:(id)anObject
{
    [_backingStore addObject:anObject];
}

-(void)removeLastObject
{
    [_backingStore removeLastObject];
}

-(void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject
{   
    [_backingStore replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:anObject];
}

@end
```

If you want to subclass `NSArray`, you only provide the Section titled `NSArray`.
You can now subclass from your "implementation of a custom `NSArray` subclass" and work as you wish.

Hope this helped... Peace!

Tomen =)

Comment: #1, this post is not a question. #2, the reason you normally wouldn't want to subclass `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` is because they are class clusters - more information here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html

Comment: Who said "you can't subclass NSMutableArray and NSArray"? Apple even mentions in the documentation how to do it.

Comment: but they seem to discourage it. otherwise it wouldnt be that hard to just subclass it. i seems to me there is explicit code that checks and prevents subclassing without providing a custom backing store

Comment: You indeed can subclass NSArray, which Apple states in their own documentation.  From the [NSArray class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html): "There is typically little reason to subclass NSArray. The class does well what it is designed to do—maintain an ordered collection of objects. But there are situations where a custom NSArray object might come in handy."

Comment: Also, read the "Subclassing Notes" section of the documentation, which describes exactly what you need to do for subclassing NSArray.

Comment: Not a question. Should be removed i think.

Comment: i edited the article and integrated your feedback. The intention of the article is to provide lesser experienced coders with a simple (google-findable) way to subclass NSArray and NSMutableArray. I thought it would be classified as community wiki. It would be nice if you read over the introductory section again and upvote it, if you think it better reflects the topic. Hope to hear your positive feedback =)

Comment: Apple doesn't disallow people from subclassing NS(Mutable)Array, but I think they do a pretty good job of conveying the fact that it's not a good idea for most users. Unless you have a darn good reason why you need an array that behaves different from NS(Mutable)Array, subclassing it is generally a waste of effort and performance.

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing `NSMutableArray` and backing it with an `NSMutableArray` is a pointless and horrific idea. If you're going to subclass something as basic as **NS(Mutable)Array**, at least have a reason to do so. For example, I have subclasses `NSMutableArray` and backed it with a C array to make it act as a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), so insertion and removal at the front are just as fast as at the back. (Google `CHCircularBuffer` if you're curious.)
 However, most of the time there is little or no point in subclassing. Also, although it may be simple to create a trivial subclass, it is NOT trivial to create a useful and meaningful subclass.

Comment: This is a great example that it is not necessary to subclass NSMutableArray in most cases. According to the documentation adding or removing objects at either end takes constant time (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-BBCCJBIF ).

Comment: I recommend reading [Exposing NSMutableArray](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/) by Bartosz Ciechanowski. It’s very relevant.